# Filtering rows in a group based on group properties

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a tibble with a grouping variable and a logical variable that indicates whether a row is a primary response for that group.

I want to do the following:

1. If any row in a `group` is marked as `is_primary` keep that row but none of the others in the group
2. If no row in `group` is marked with `is_primary`, keep them all
3. Filter the rows based on the above

Here is some example data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(group=c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C"),
               is_primary=c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),
               value=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
```

In the above example, I'd like to keep all the `A` rows, because there is no row with `is_primary==TRUE`, keep only the second `B` row, and keep the last two `C` rows.

I thought the obvious solution would be something like:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(keep_row=ifelse(any(is_primary),is_primary,TRUE))
```

But this results in the following, which doesn't meet the criteria above.

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
  group is_primary value keep_row
  <chr> <lgl>      <dbl> <lgl>   
1 A     FALSE          1 TRUE    
2 A     FALSE          2 TRUE    
3 A     FALSE          3 TRUE    
4 B     FALSE          4 FALSE   
5 B     TRUE           5 FALSE   
6 C     FALSE          6 FALSE   
7 C     FALSE          7 FALSE   
8 C     TRUE           8 FALSE   
9 C     TRUE           9 FALSE
```

However, if I make an intermediary variable that indicated whether the group has a primary key it works.

```r
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(has_primary=ifelse(any(is_primary),TRUE,FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(keep_row=ifelse(has_primary,is_primary,TRUE))
```

This results in `keep_row` being correct:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   group [3]
  group is_primary value has_primary keep_row
  <chr> <lgl>      <dbl> <lgl>       <lgl>   
1 A     FALSE          1 FALSE       TRUE    
2 A     FALSE          2 FALSE       TRUE    
3 A     FALSE          3 FALSE       TRUE    
4 B     FALSE          4 TRUE        FALSE   
5 B     TRUE           5 TRUE        TRUE    
6 C     FALSE          6 TRUE        FALSE   
7 C     FALSE          7 TRUE        FALSE   
8 C     TRUE           8 TRUE        TRUE    
9 C     TRUE           9 TRUE        TRUE
```

What is going on in `ifelse` that the first solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use an `if/else` condition to return the rows when there is no TRUE element in 'is_primary' or `else` return only the rows where 'is_primary' is TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    filter(if(!any(is_primary)) TRUE else is_primary)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
#  group is_primary value
#  <chr> <lgl>      <dbl>
#1 A     FALSE          1
#2 A     FALSE          2
#3 A     FALSE          3
#4 B     TRUE           5
#5 C     TRUE           8
#6 C     TRUE           9
```

It can be also done with a `|` condition

```
data %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   filter(!any(is_primary) | is_primary)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
#  group is_primary value
#  <chr> <lgl>      <dbl>
#1 A     FALSE          1
#2 A     FALSE          2
#3 A     FALSE          3
#4 B     TRUE           5
#5 C     TRUE           8
#6 C     TRUE           9
```

---

Or another option is

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(sum(is_primary) == 0 | is_primary)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   group [3]
#  group is_primary value
#  <chr> <lgl>      <dbl>
#1 A     FALSE          1
#2 A     FALSE          2
#3 A     FALSE          3
#4 B     TRUE           5
#5 C     TRUE           8
#6 C     TRUE           9
```

---

Or using `slice`

```
data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  slice(if(!any(is_primary)) row_number() else which(is_primary))
```

---

A `data.table` option of the above would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[data[, .I[!any(is_primary)|is_primary], by = group]$V1]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
data[with(data, !ave(is_primary, group, FUN = any) | is_primary),]
```

---

The issue with `ifelse` is that according to `?ifelse`

> ifelse(test, yes, no)
>
> If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled. yes will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously for no.

In the  OP's code

```
 ifelse(any(is_primary),TRUE,FALSE)
```

`any` returns a logical vector of `length` 1.  According to `?any`

> The value is a logical vector of length one.

Based on the `ifelse` documentation above, these values are recycled

Comment: This is demonstrating that eitehr (a) the `dplyr::if` function is different than the base `if` function, or (b) that `group_by` is an implicit looping control construct.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty complete. I guess I was surprised that the condition in `ifelse` controls length. To me, `ifelse(TRUE,c(1,2),c(3,4))` returning `[1] 1` is unexpected behavior. So it's not really about `ifelse` recycling values, but rather truncating to the length of the condition.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is that `ifelse()` returns a vector that's the length of the the input. When you pass `ifelse(any(),...)` that `any()` will only return a single vector that's repeated for the group.  You can see that with

```
x <- c(F,T,F,T, F)
ifelse(any(x), x, TRUE)
# [1] FALSE
```

Notice how only one value is returned. An `ifelse()` is not just a shortcut for a proper `if \ else` statement. It is a vectorized function so be careful not to use it when you are trying to conditionally execute code in a non-vectorized way.

Another way to express your filter would be

```
data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(any(is_primary) & is_primary | !any(is_primary))
```